# Integrating Google Login with Cognito & API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am looking to integrate [Google Login](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) (not the Google+ one provided by Cognito, I don't want to require users to be Google+ users) with Cognito & API Gateway.

Am I on the right track?

- I have added `account.google.com` to Cognito's Federated Identities pool
- After login:

  ```
  AWS.config.region = "ap-northeast-2"
  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: 'ap-northeast-2:31cc246c-bd2e-46ee-91da-2b8eefcf0745',
      Logins: {
        "accounts.google.com": googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token
      }
  })
  ```

Am I on the right track so far? But with this alone I do not have a cognito token?

I think I need to follow one of the flows from [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html). But which?

Do I just use Enchanced (Simplified)? And call `GetId` & `GetCredentialsForIdentity`? But do I even need `GetId`. I think I just need a token?

Any examples or guidance? I don't want to just bruteforce whatever works but not understand whats the use case of each flow ... can someone help explain?

Answer (score 2):

By configuring `AWS.config.credentials` you are effectively configuring the credentials object used to obtain an AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key automagically.

The `CognitoIdentityCredentials` ([see here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html)) object establishes these for you when you attempt to call any other AWS library, for example S3. If you need access to the keys themselves, call either `AWS.config.credentials.refresh()` ([refresh](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html#refresh-property)) or `AWS.config.credentials.get()` and inside the callback you can then access `AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey` ([secretAccessKey](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html#secretAccessKey-property)) etc.

Finally, if you're looking to obtain a Open ID token using a federated identity, for use in a similar fashion to Cognito User Pools - as far as I'm aware, this is not currently possible. The closest you can get is [GetOpenIdToken](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdToken.html).

Comment: So whats the use case of federated identity if its not really an "alternative" to user pools? Am I correct to say its intended to allow access to AWS resources via say Google?